# Angular 2 "this" unable to access global variable in nested function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, typescript, angular

I'm quite new to Angular 2. Would like to ask how can I access "task_title" in the startTimer().
All I got from the console.log() is undefined. I believe the "this" was pointing to the function itself so I couldn't get the value of "task_title".

Is there anyway I can access to global variable in Typescript in a nested function?

```
export class DashboardComponent {

    task_title: string;

    myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer, 2000);

    updateTask(event: any){
        clearTimeout(this.myTimer);
        this.task_title = event.target.value;
        this.myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer, 2000);
    }

    startTimer() {
        console.log(this.task_title);
        this.myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer, 2000);
    };
}
```

Result: Undefined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use arrow functions or `.bind(this)` to retain the scope of `this`

```
myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer.bind(this), 2000);
myTimer = setTimeout(() => this.startTimer(), 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use reference for this like var self=this

```
export class DashboardComponent {

var self=this;


task_title: string;

myTimer = setTimeout(self.startTimer, 2000);

updateTask(event: any){
    clearTimeout(self.myTimer);
    self.task_title = event.target.value;
    self.myTimer = setTimeout(self.startTimer, 2000);
}

startTimer() {
    console.log(self.task_title);
    self.myTimer = setTimeout(self.startTimer, 2000);
};
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. When I put it into my code, I used a variable name like classScope or outerScope instead of self.

Answer (score 1):

Use call or apply

```
myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer.call(this), 2000);
```

```
myTimer = setTimeout(this.startTimer.apply(this), 2000);
```